# Workaround for Using a Type Parameter as a Generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a `DatabaseEngine` interface, which takes one type parameter: `ResultType`. This type parameter is the interface of a query result, as specified by the specific database driver; for MSSQL, it would be the `IResult` interface: `DatabaseEngine<IResult>`. This type is *not* the rowset received from a query, but is the "wrapper" that includes not only the rowset, but also various metadata (including fields, affected rows, executed SQL, etc).

The `IResult` interface from the MSSQL library takes one type parameter, which is the interface defining rows of data being returned. This is a general trend for most database libraries I've used.

The `DatabaseEngine` interface has a `toDataFrame` property, which is a function that performs a manipulation (the details of which are arbitrary for this question) on data that has been retrieved from the database. This function has a type parameter T, which encompasses the rows of objects coming from the database; it's one and only parameter should be the result set that has come from the database driver (eg. IResult). However, IResult was encompassed earlier by a type parameter on it's own; so it would need to be `ResultType<T>`, but this does not work.

TL;DR: I want a type that would be as follows:

```js
interface DatabaseEngine<ResultType> {
    ...
    toDataFrame<T>(result: ResultType<T>): DataFrame<T>
}

// where T is the object type of the rowset from the database, and ResultType is the library-specific wrapper for a query result
```

A desired usage example of such would be the following:

```js
import mssql from 'mssql'

const msSqlDatabaseEngine: DatabaseEngine<IResult> = {
    ...
    toDataFrame<T>: (result) => {
        ... // do something with result and return a dataframe
        // due to typings, result is inferred as IResult<T>
    }
}

const queryResult = mssql.connect({ ... }).query('SELECT * from Employees') // returns an object of type IResult<Employee> (assuming Employee is a type defined elsewhere, the details of which aren't relevant)
const df = msSqlDatabaseEngine.toDataFrame(queryResult) // queryResult can be used directly, since the compiler will infer that the inner generic T is Employee in this function call
```

I understand that this is a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) that is still open. The various other SO questions I've read don't quite answer this need I have, in that they don't try to combine type parameters from different places with one as a generic. Is there a potential workaround for what I'm trying to achieve?

I tried the above interface as is, but gave errors saying that "ResultType is not generic", which of course it isn't. I tried to make ResultType generic, but this is not recognised by TypeScript, since it is part of a generic. I'm looking for either a set of utility types that can achieve this, or a workaround that would achieve the same or similar result.

Comment: Please add an usage example (example ResultType, example function call)

Comment: Is the number of possible ResultType-s limiten and listable in code?

Comment: @Dimava I've made some edits as requested. The number of possible ResultType's can be limited - they are only Database implementations, which can certainly be listed.

Comment: By the way, Have you considered Prisma or something?

Comment: Yes, Prisma or another ORM may be a helpful addition. But I've always been left wanting when I've used one in the past, so would like to skip that layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can infer `T` from `IResult<T> | IOtherResult<T> | ...`,

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXvxLm)

```
import mssql from 'mssql'

type MyDbResult<T> = { db: 'my-db', value: T }

type ResultType<T> =
    | mssql.IResult<T>
    | MyDbResult<T>

type UnwrapResultType<T> =
    | T extends ResultType<infer V> ? V : never
    // | T extends mssql.IResult<infer V> ? V
    // : T extends MyDbResult<infer V> ? V
    // : never;

type DataFrame<T> = T[][]

interface DatabaseEngine<BaseResultType extends ResultType<any>> {
    //                   ^ force result to be limited to ThisDBResult<any>
    toDataFrame<T extends BaseResultType>(result: T): DataFrame<UnwrapResultType<T>>
}

const msSqlDatabaseEngine: DatabaseEngine<mssql.IResult<any>> = {
    toDataFrame(
        result /* : result: T extends mssql.IResult<any> */
    ) /* : DataFrame<UnwrapResultType<T>> */ {
        return [[]]
    }
}
const mySqlDatabaseEngine: DatabaseEngine<MyDbResult<any>> = {
    toDataFrame(
        result /* T extends MyDbResult<any> */
    ) /* DataFrame<UnwrapResultType<T>> */ {
        return [[]]
    }
}

const con = await mssql.connect('')
const queryResult = await con.query<{ employee: true }>('SELECT * from Employees')
//    ^?
// const queryResult: mssql.IResult<{ employee: true; }>
const df = msSqlDatabaseEngine.toDataFrame(queryResult)
//    ^?
// const df: DataFrame<{ employee: true; }>

const myQueryResult: MyDbResult<number> = { db: 'my-db', value: 123 }
const mf = mySqlDatabaseEngine.toDataFrame(myQueryResult)
//    ^?
// const mf: DataFrame<number>
```